# Does TAction.OnUpdate event degrade the performance?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tlistview, taction

In Delphi XE7, I use this trick to automatically enable or disable a toolbar button ("Edit ListView Item") according to whether an item in the ListView is selected or not, to prevent the user to click on the button if there is no ListView Item selected:

- Put a TActionList on a VCL Form.
- In the ActionList create an action `actTest`.
- Put a TButton on the form.
- Assign the action `actTest` to the button.
- Put a TListView on the form.
- In the ListView create two items.
- In the `OnUpdate` event of the `actTest` action write:

  ```
   procedure TForm1.actTestUpdate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     actTest.Enabled := ListView1.SelCount > 0;
     CodeSite.Send('actTestUpdate'); // gets fired very often!
   end;
  ```

Now you can see that the button becomes enabled or disabled according to whether an item in the ListView is selected or not, independently from whether you select/deselect items with the mouse or with the keyboard or programmatically.

However, in the CodeSite Live Viewer I can see that the `actTestUpdate` event is fired **continuously and very often**, so the statement `actTest.Enabled := ListView1.SelCount > 0;` gets executed VERY OFTEN.

So my question is: Does this degrade the performance? If yes, is there another trick to achieve the above purpose?

Comment: The `TAction.OnUpdate` intention is to do what you are doing, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/TActionOnUpdate_(Delphi)

Comment: You are doing it as was intended. But, it is an unecessary wasting of resources. What's worse, there might be situations where you need to e.g. disable a certain action in the middle of a method execution and using the `OnUpdate` way may lead to doing it *unsafely late*. I'm trying to completely avoid `OnUpdate` personally.

Comment: @TLama Which alternative would you suggest?

Comment: I would update the action state right when something happens. In this case when the list view's underlying model selection changes.

Comment: @TLama How would you do that? I've tried them all. Remember, the goal is to update the button independently from whether you select/deselect items with the mouse or with the keyboard.

Comment: The crux is that TListView.OnSelectItem is triggered several times on selection change, and the various click and keyboard events each cover only either the mouse or the keyboard. So TListView lacks a proper event type for this purpose.

Comment: The `OnSelectItem` event should be fired only when the selection state of an item changes and it is so the ideal trigger for this update (whether you update a model, or the action itself when having no view model concept). That's better than wasteful sending of `LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT` messages to get the selected item count whenever the application goes idle (and nothing in the selection actually changes).

Comment: @TLama _...may lead to doing it unsafely late_ in which case you can update manually anyway.

Comment: OnSelectItem fires twice when a selection is changing. Once with "selected" false, disable your button there. And once with "selected" true, enable your button then. Doesn't look like excessive processing..

Comment: As I read it your OnUpdate is being fired repeatedly even when there is no user interaction. Is that so? If so, please make a repro.

Comment: @David, [`OnUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.OnUpdate), *occurs when the application is idle...*, that's where the wasting origins.

Comment: @TLama It occurs when the app **becomes** idle. Not when it **is** idle. That means, when the message queue has just been emptied. So if no input messages, or timers, or paint messages are pulled from the queue it won't fire. Now, if user has a timer running, OnUpdate will happen after every timer event.

Comment: @David I'm pretty sure OP means by _continuously and very often_ that he didn't notice that without mouse movement.

Comment: @NGLN I'd like to be sure. If user is sitting there providing no input and OnIdle is firing repeatedly, it would be nice to know why. I've see OnIdle lead to significant CPU utilization when an app is idle.

Comment: @David, which happens still unecessarily often (and *randomly*) for such purpose. I'm happy to update my action states just when they need, not when the application becomes idle, sun goes down, or moon enters a certain phase :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I am sitting here at my desk, no mouse moving, no keyboard typing, having no timer running and watching the messages running down like a waterfall in CodeSite Live Viewer. It's very relaxing, better than an aquarium...

Comment: @user1580348: Then there is most likely a timer running in your code, or maybe inside one of your UI controls.  You can use the `TApplication.OnMessage` event to verify that.

Comment: Yes, timer is the likely explanation. OnIdle is quite crude.

Comment: I was hit by the same problem, if you have many actions you will find high cpu usage, even when you do nothing, you can set `Application.ActionUpDateDelay` to higher value so that the event fires less often.

Answer (score 9):

If you have (or plan to have) many actions you might want to set Application.ActionUpdateDelay to e.g. 50 milliseconds. This can improve the performance noticeable.

Also, again if you have many actions, I would suggest you try to use TForm.UpdateActions instead of defining TAction.OnUpdate for each action. It will make the code more readable.

Comment: yes this is the problem, I would take a higher value though.

Answer (score 5):

#### Generally

Yes, an [`OnUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.OnUpdate) event handler takes time, just as any other routine does. Multiple handlers take a multiple of that time. The gross of all that code will evaluate conditions resulting in just nothing to do. In that sense, you could conclude that this update mechanism degrades performance. Especially considering these update events occur quite often:

> Occurs when the application is idle or when the action list updates.

That could be a reason to spare its use. But you should realize that the evaluation of a single expression mostly does not take that much time. Also, realize that regardless of action updates, your application performs (much more heavy) calculations and operations on every single mouse move.

When you keep the code duration in action update events to a minimal, e.g. no password checking via a database connection, then performance will appear just normal. If you háve lengthy operations linked to updating actions, then fall back on manual updates in those specific situations.

Note that performance can be slightly gained by not using the individual `OnUpdate` events of the Actions, but the [`OnUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ActnList.TActionList.OnUpdate) event of the ActionList instead which has a `Handled` parameter to cancel further processing, with the additional benefit of centralization and categorization.

#### Specifically

Your `ListView1.SelCount` sends a WinAPI message to the control to retrieve the selection count. That is a tiny operation and I would not bother its time needed.

An alternative is to update the action in the ListView's [`OnSelectItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OnSelectItem) event. That event will catch all selection changes due to mouse and keyboard interaction, as well as setting the individual items'
[`Selected`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.Selected) property:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
begin
  actTest.Enabled := ListView1.SelCount > 0;
end;
```

However, the ListView nor the VCL do not provide anything to signal only between `SelCount = 0` and `SelCount > 0`, so you will evaluate that line of code more then strictly necessary anyway.

Assuming `MultiSelect` is true, you could also count the selection changes yourself to eliminate the need for calling `SelCount`:

```
  private
    FListViewSelected: Longbool;

procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
begin
  if Selected then
    Inc(FListViewSelected)
  else
    Dec(FListViewSelected);
  actTest.Enabled := FListViewSelected;
end;
```

Or test for the selected item being nil:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
begin
  actTest.Enabled := ListView1.Selected <> nil;
end;
```

But then again, there really is no reason left for not using the `OnUpdate` event:

```
procedure TForm1.ActionList1Update(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  actTest.Enabled := ListView1.Selected <> nil;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Comment: NGLN, if you provide a working example with `OnSelectItem` which has no flaws, I will propose you for the next Nobel Prize. I have tried it...

Comment: @user Do you understand OnIdle, when it fires, why that influences OnUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

The Action update events are (mostly) executed inside Application.Idle. As long as you don't do time critical things inside the event handlers there should be no noticeable performance degradation.

Comment: It's not about time criticality (the thing itself depends on time spend), but about time taking/duration (the thing itself having consequence for things to come).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem no wanting to repeatedly call control update while the app is idle, and came up with the following solution:

You could write an event which triggers [OnExecute](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Actions.TContainedActionList.OnExecute) action and compare which action it was triggered from, by using its `Action` pointer parameter. *After* executing the desired action's code but still in the `OnExecute` event, you can call some sort of `UpdateAllControlsVisibilityState()` procedure which could update your buttons enabled/disabled states for you at the end of this event for example. E.g.

```
procedure TForm1.ActionManager1Execute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin

  if Action = DesiredAction1 then
     // Execute code for DesiredAction1...
  else if Action = DesiredAction2 then
     // Execute code for DesiredAction2...
  // ...

  UpdateAllControlsVisibilityState; // Write procedure here to update your controls

end;
```

In this case, the `OnExecute` would be called **only once** and only after you trigger a certain action, with the appropriate control visibility update. Also, by managing it that way, you get centralized action management rather than having each action `OnExecute` event.

I have tested which `OnExecute` event gets called first and it appears that the `OnExecute` of the TActionManager gets called first, then the `OnExecute` event of a particular action gets called next (if assigned), at least in 10.4.2 which I am using at the moment and I really like the centralized management of all the actions which makes debugging much easier (for me at least).

It also depends on the `Handled` parameter - if the `OnExecute` event handler does not set its `Handled` parameter to `True`, the application’s `OnActionExecute` event occurs next.